# Python poll - attribute error

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to poll a process using `poll()` from python. [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)

I don't understand, I am supplying an integral value for it to poll. for example: the value is `14870`

```
14870
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    parse_file(input_csv[0])
  File "test.py", line 24, in parse_file
    ret = pid[r].poll()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

I failed to find anywhere in the documentation about what datatype it is..

Comment: It's right there in the link you provided: `Instances of the Popen class have the following methods:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could execute the following:

```
from os import system
_proc_status = system('/proc/' + str(pid) + '/status')
```

Answer (score 2):

`poll` is a method of the `Popen` object just like `pid` is an attribute of the `Popen` object:

```
process = Popen(['some','command'])
print(process.pid)
process.poll()
```

Comment: I get the pid from a csv file. so, for polling, I only have the pid.

Comment: Then you would need to ask the system if that PID is alive or not.
As user... sad, to use the poll() function you would need to own the process in question within your application.

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)`
`procs[a] = p.pid`
`with open(save, 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(a)+ ","+ str(p.pid) + '\n')`